# HTML > Rotate and scale an image based on window and image size

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am working in HTML / Javascript and am tyring to have an image be resized based on the window size. The image will take up all of the window space but maintain its aspect ratio when being resized. Also, the image will rotate and resize if the window size becomes greater than its longest side.

For example, if an image is more wide than tall, and the window size changes to be very tall the image should rotate and resize in order to maximize the window space while keeping the aspect ratio of the image the same. The image should also be centered on the screen so it will have the same dead speace on either side of the image.

I am not able to get this to work. Here is my code so far.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<link href="test.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    function resize_canvas(){

        var main_canvas=document.getElementById("test");
        var cxt=main_canvas.getContext("2d");
        var img=new Image();

        var ratio = 1;
        var changed = 1;
        var mid = 1;            
        var srcLink = "tall.JPG"; // test with tall and wide pics

        main_canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        main_canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        img.src=srcLink;

        if(window.innerWidth > window.innerHeight){ // if window port is wider than tall

            changed = window.innerWidth / (img.width / img.height);


            mid = window.innerHeight / 2;             

            img.onload = function()
            {

              if (img.width < img.height){

                ratio = window.innerHeight / img.height;
                changed = img.width * ratio;    


                cxt.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);

                cxt.drawImage(img, 0, -img.height,changed,window.innerWidth);


              } else {

                cxt.drawImage(img,0,mid,window.innerWidth,changed); 
              }



            } // end img onload call



        }else{ // if window port is taller than wide


            ratio = window.innerHeight / img.height;
            changed = img.width * ratio;    


            mid = window.innerWidth / 2;               

            img.onload = function()
            {  

              if (img.width > img.height){

                ratio = window.innerWidth / img.width;
                changed = img.height * ratio;   


                mid = window.innerHeight / 2 - changed / 2;


                cxt.rotate(90 * Math.PI / 180);
                cxt.drawImage(img, 0, -img.height,window.innerHeight,changed);

              } else {

                cxt.drawImage(img,mid,0,changed,window.innerHeight);
              }



            } // end img on load


        } // end window size else block

    } // end resize function
</script>


</head>
<body onload="resize_canvas();" onresize="resize_canvas();">

    <canvas id="test"> canvas not supported </canvas>

</body>
</html>


css file

html, body {
 width:  100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0px;
}

#test
{
    width: 100%; height: auto;

}
```

I spent many days on this as I am just learning but I'm running out of ideas on how to solve the problem. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of it does not work?

Comment: I am able to scale the image but I am not able to center the image properly. Also, when the image has to be rotated the scaling and centering does not appear to work. The image is either partially off the screen or when I try to resize the image it just doesn't appear. I am not sure exactly where my error is.

Comment: Which browser(s) and version(s) do you need to support?

Comment: I highly recommend creating a demo at http://jsfiddle.net.

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            window.onload = function() {
                var fitAspectRatio = function(srcWidth, srcHeight, fitWidth, fitHeight) {
                    if(fitHeight > fitWidth) {
                        theta = Math.PI / 2;
                        var temp = srcWidth;
                        srcWidth = srcHeight;
                        srcHeight = temp;
                    } else {
                        theta = 0;
                    }
                    var ratio = [fitWidth / srcWidth, fitHeight / srcHeight];
                    ratio = Math.min(ratio[0], ratio[1]);
                    return {
                        width : srcWidth * ratio,
                        height : srcHeight * ratio,
                        angle : theta
                    };
                };
                var img = new Image();
                img.src = 'tall.JPG';

                var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas1");
                var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

                window.onresize = function() {
                    var newsize = fitAspectRatio(img.width, img.height, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
                    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
                    canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
                    img.centerX = canvas.width / 2;
                    img.centerY = canvas.height / 2;
                    if(newsize.angle != 0) {
                        ctx.translate(img.centerX, img.centerY);
                        ctx.rotate(newsize.angle);
                        ctx.translate(-img.centerX, -img.centerY);
                        ctx.drawImage(img, (canvas.width - newsize.height) / 2, (canvas.height - newsize.width) / 2, newsize.height, newsize.width);
                    } else {
                        ctx.drawImage(img, (canvas.width - newsize.width) / 2, (canvas.height - newsize.height) / 2, newsize.width, newsize.height);
                    }
                };
                window.onresize();
            };

        </script>
        <style>
        body {
            background: #001;
        }
        #canvas1 {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="canvas1"></canvas>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for that great post. It works perfectly for pictures that are wider than they are tall. However, I am just trying to modify it so it will handle pictures that are taller than they are wide. The photo will rotate fine when I reverse the "fitHeight > fitWidth" comparison but the scaling of the image is off.

Comment: @nomaam: The provided code should/does handle both image orientations without modification. What web browser are you using?

Comment: Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnt1/dawmy/1/) test. (scale using the frame dividers)